# Grouping Tabs in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau report with about 30 tabs in.

I'd like to group them up into 4/5 categories to make it easier to navigate. Preferably with folders or a menu.

I can not see any obvious way of doing this and a few searches suggests that this is a feature Tableau have not included, which surprises me since I would have thought they would be all about making data presentable!

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you have a tableau workbook with 30 tabs or a dashboard with 30 tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Grouping tabs would appear to be a feature request ([here's an Idea in the Tableau Community for this functionality](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1031))

As a more general point, having a complex workbook with that many tabs can potentially lead to performance issues, so it might be worth investigating whether the workbook can be split into smaller parts.

Answer (score 0):

As of Tableau 9.3, there is no explicit feature for grouping worksheet (tabs) in a workbook. But there are a couple of other features that can help you keep large workbooks organized.

You can assign colors to tabs (via a right click menu) and of course move them around to whatever order and color scheme makes sense to you. The slide sorter view is helpful for organizing tabs.

You can also hide worksheets to reduce clutter (again via right click). That is useful for hiding views that only exist to be included in some dashboards. (You can only hide a worksheet if it appears on at least one dashboard)